# R studio List and Dataframes auto name completion not working anymore

Tags: r, rstudio

Suddenly R Studio stopped auto completing my list and data frame contents when entering `mylist$` then pressing `Tab`. The result message I get is

> No matches

I tried that on very simple lists or data frames like:

```
 simpledataset <- data.frame(a=rep(0,100),b=rep(1,100))
```

However, when I load the dataset Mtcars, it correctly shows the column names.

I reset `%localappdata%\RStudio-Desktop` by renaming it, but didn't change anything.

Any idea of what could be the cause of that?

Comment: Does tab completion work for filling in names of objects, like the data.frame name, simpldataset? What about completion of file paths?

Comment: Hello lmo, it perfectly works for names of objects, I tried it for file paths (never had done it before so not sure I did it correctly) and it didn't work.

Comment: for file name autocomplete, you need to put your cursor between two quote marks then hit tab... it should show a dropdown of all files in your getwd().

Comment: Indeed thanks for that, then filename autocompletion works. I just realized something, everything works fine in a new session, until I execute this instruction `modelFit<-train(training[[1]] ~ ., method="glm", preProcess="pca", data=training)` raising the warning 
>Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.

Comment: You might try setting the "show code completions" to "manually (Tab)" and see if that works.

Comment: Hey Imo, same thing, works for names, not for columns...

Comment: @Olivierhbh I am also facing the same issue? Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @mockash, unfortunately no. But I stopped using R, I'm full Python now. Good luck with your issue.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a bug in the autocompletion system that is occasionally triggered when certain packages are loaded, or the byte-compiler optimization setting is increased. You might try checking a few things:

- What is the value of `compiler::getCompilerOption("optimize")`? Autocompletion is known to fail when this value is equal to `3` in the current RStudio release (v0.99.896). You can try running `compiler::setCompilerOptions(optimize = 2)` to resolve this.
- What packages do you have loaded? You can try loading packages one-by-one to see which affects RStudio's ability to provide autocompletions.

Finally, there should be a fix for this in the preview version of RStudio -- you can try it out at https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/.

Comment: Hello Kevin, `compiler::getCompilerOption("optimize")` is set to 2. 

Autocompletion stops working right after I call the train function from the caret package, using this command `modelFit<-train(training[[1]] ~ ., method="glm", preProcess="pca", data=training)`.

Raising this Warning:

>Warning message: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo, : There were missing values in resampled performance measures.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Tools>Global Options**... and set autocomplete there.

[image]

Comment: Hello Brandon, thanks for your suggestion but my settings were already set up as yours.