# Auto complete for dataframes not working in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I installed R and Rstudio in my new system and imported csv files using Rstudio. 
While working on the dataframe and when entering `df$` then pressing `Tab` I am not getting the column names and the result message I get is

> No matches

However the auto complete seems to work on inbuilt data frames like `mtcars`. I could see a similar question posted earlier [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029392/r-studio-list-and-dataframes-auto-name-completion-not-working-anymore). But there is no answer. Any suggestions please.

Btw I am working on R 3.4 and Rstudio version is 0.99.879

Comment: What about updating RStudio?

Comment: I have not updated RStudio but this was working earlier in my previous system and it suddenly stopped working now.

Comment: Do you have a reason to keep not updating it? Perhaps it has some incompatibilities with your new system. That's especially likely to be the reason because at the time when your linked question was posted, the most recent RStudio version also was 0.99. There have been a number of bug fixes regarding autocompletion since then.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example? Perhaps you can try to see if `as.data.frame(df)` changes something, also, what is the result of `dim(df)` and `colnames(df)` ?

Comment: @Julius I had to get few permissions in updating to latest version and yes it is working fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the same version software was used under the previous system, it is likely that some incompatibilities arose under the new one.

It is particularly likely since the most recent RStudio version available at the time of posting [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029392/r-studio-list-and-dataframes-auto-name-completion-not-working-anymore) also [was 0.99](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/release-notes/). Moreover, a number of autocompletion-related bug fixes [have been released](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/release-notes/) since then. Hence, updating your software, especially RStudio, should help.